# KDE Driver Manager Collecting Information Forever

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with the Kubuntu Desktop Environment (KDE) and default Kernel (4.4.0-79-generic
), and whenever I try to go to the `Driver Management Software` section of `All Settings`, it seems to be stuck in `Collecting Information` section forever. I think over an hour is an unreasonable amount of time, so it appears to be hanging. How can I fix this? Are there any diagnostics I should run from terminal to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I agree that's too long. Try `sudo ubuntu-drivers debug` (--help for other options). (The output I get is too cryptic to interpret, but you might get informative error messages...)

Comment: Video cards are the most common proprietary drivers; sometimes also wifi adapters, bluetooth devices, audio devices, modem or broadband devices. Do you have any  specialised or weird devices? (Subjective I know!)